# Incorrect time showing after converting to date format - PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Below is the time string I have,

```
'2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00'
```

I tried to convert this to date format using below php code.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00'));
```

And i am getting **`2019-12-30 10:12:33`** as the output. It seems date getting correctly but time not.

How to display the time also correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that the time of your PHP server is involved here (and also, that server's time is in IST, telling by the 30 minute shift)

Comment: Thanks@TimBiegeleisen for your comment. Any ways to get correct time as in the input string?

Comment: try setting your timezone please date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: In my application its already set to date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time string '2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00' contains time zone information of +11:00.
With date() the date and time are converted into the local time zone of your server. For example, I get "2019-12-30 05:42:33" (Timezone Europe/Berlin).

You can set a different time zone with date_default_timezone_set() or use DateTime to output the time for a location with the time zone "+11:00".

```
echo date_create('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2019-12-30 15:42:33
```

strtotime () returns an integer timestamp. The Iformation of the Timezone +11:00 are lost in the process, but are processed when the time stamp is determined.
The DateTime object always has a time zone.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(date_create('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00'));
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-12-30 15:42:33.891000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+11:00"
}
```

**Note (Update):**

When creating a DateTime object, the optional parameter for the time zone is only taken into account if the time string does not contain a time zone!

```
var_dump(new DateTime('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891 +11:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-12-30 15:42:33.891000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+11:00"
}

//without +11:00
var_dump(new DateTime('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-12-30 15:42:33.891000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This date and time format relates to the  "Zulu time" (UTC). UTC is refereed as Universal Time Coordinated. It is also known as “Z time” or “Zulu Time”.

You should change your timezone by some command like below code:

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-12-30T15:42:33.891+11:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or, for having more tools you can use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) library.

Comment: The new DateTimeZone ('UTC') has no effect here since a time zone already exists in the time string. See also remark in my post.